# casting to int python with symbol

Tags: python

so I want to cast these to ints but when I use the built-in function int() I get an error, I don't want to make a custom function that checks the first character,so I was wondering if there was a way to convert these to ints.

[image: error]
[image: strings]

Comment: I suspect it's not really a minus sign, but some other Unicode character that looks similar.

Comment: Please provide *all code/data as formatted text*. Do **not** post images. More importantly, `int('-1')` works just fine. I *suspect* that you dash is a different kind of dash... i.e. not `chr(45)` but `chr(8209)`

Comment: What does `CDMAOutput[idx].encode().hex()` show?

Comment: Looks like int should handle this strings.  Can you provide code and the error produced?

Comment: Hi the hex is 'e2889231' @md2perpe

Comment: the error code is at the first line with the blue highlight @William

Comment: @cber11  you **must** provide a [mcve]

Comment: When I did `.encode().hex()` on `'-1'` I got `'2d31'` so there seems to be some unicode character that is not the normal minus sign in your string.

Comment: @md2perpe alternatively, I find using just `list(map(ord, data))` much more clear

Comment: The minus sign you have there is the mathematical symbol "[minus sign](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm)" which differs from the ordinary sign "[hyphen-minus](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm)".

Comment: @md2perpe what would I put in that list(map(ord, data))? THanks!

Comment: You can do `int(CDMAOutput[idx].replace(chr(8722), '-')))` in your code.

Comment: @cber11 `list(map(ord, CDMAOutput[idx]))`, but again, more importantly, you **must provide a [mcve]**

Comment: It would have been better to ask @juanpa.arrivillaga about `list(map(ord, data))`, but `data` should be the string you have, i.e. `CDMAOutput[idx]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what we found in the discussion under your question:

You have the mathematical unicode symbol "[minus sign](https://unicode-table.com/en/2212/)" instead of the ASCII symbol "[hyphen-minus](https://unicode-table.com/en/002D/)" in your string.

The problem can be solved by replacing the non-workning symbol with the working one:

```py
int(CDMAOutput[idx].replace(chr(8722), '-')))
```